# Inverse square law for non-point sources?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

Assuming I have a light diffuser with an area A (approximately planar, not spherical) and measure the light intensity directly at the surface (23 mW/cm^2), how could I determine the intensity at distance d away from the diffuser?

I'm aware, that I can't simply use the inverse square law for near distances, but nevertheless, I can assume that any point on the surface still follows the inverse square law, the problem is, that the photons emittet by the sourronding points add up again making the intensity greater. How can I calculate the correct intensity from a (rather near) distance d away?

Comment: If you have a measuring device then you can just measure it at set points and form some sort of empirical law instead of attempting a much harder calculation.

Comment: @Triatticus I don't have a measuring device, those are values given from another source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since every point from the diffuser is a *point source*, each can be treated as such with $\frac{d\sigma}{r^2}$ intensity propagation, where $d\sigma$ denotes the surface density of the sources. The real question remains how to add these elementary sources up. If the diffuser acts as an essentially noncoherent spatial source, such as a greasy paper, then you can just go ahead and integrate over the surface to get the received power
$P({\mathbf r}) = \int \frac{d\sigma(\mathbf {r'}}{\mathbf {|r - r'|^2}}.$